# git won't commit changes to files already in index (preserving permissions: operation not supported)

Tags: git, permissions, commit

I'm trying to setup git as a deployment solution on a server but I encounter some pretty weird behavior using it. Basically git won't add changes for commit.

make a new repo:

```
~$ mkdir test && cd test
~/test$ git init-db

defaulting to local storage area
warning: templates not found /usr/share/git-core/templates/

~/test$ echo 'bar' > foo
~/test$ git add .
~/test$ git commit -a -n -m "initial"

cp: preserving permissions for `.git/next-index15907': Operation not supported
cp: preserving ACL for `.git/next-index15907': Operation not supported
Committing initial tree 85711ad01d3a371d1d4990f9e0902f8933b5c8b7
```

Notice there are some errors but the commit seems to have happened normally as:

```
~/test$ git status
nothing to commit
```

Now whenever I try to edit and commit files that have already been added to the index they just don't get through :

```
~/test$ echo 'baz' >> foo
~/test$ git status
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use git-update-index to mark for commit)
#
#   modified:   foo
#
nothing to commit
```

Now I'd just add the file and commit but:

```
~/test$ git add .
~/test$ git commit -a -n -m "test"
cp: preserving permissions for `.git/next-index23386': Operation not supported
cp: preserving ACL for `.git/next-index23386': Operation not supported
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use git-update-index to mark for commit)
#
#   modified:   foo
#
nothing to commit
```

Now if add a new file it will pass through the commit but any further changes won't be commited. If a "git rm" and "git add" a file it will work as expected.

Note that I am using git version 1.4.4.4 on a shared hosting server (so no updates or sudo possible).
Am I missing something in the way git worked on older versions or is it something else?

I have no idea what to do except removing and re-adding all files on each commit but I doubt that would be a good idea (the repo is about ~1gb).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1.4.4.4? That is pre-1.5, more than two years ago... Is your share accessed through a NFS mount?

Comment: I will check for more details right now

Comment: I don't really know, I can access my home dir with ssh but I don't know much about NFS mounting..